# Crash with 'Comparison method violates its general contract'

Tags: android, sorting

I get users crashing on a Collections.sort, whereas with my onw tests, the following code never crashes:

```
Collections.sort(spinnerAreaArray, new Comparator<tarifdata>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(tarifdata s1, tarifdata s2) {
                    if (s1.rating > 0 && s2.rating > 0) {
                        return s1.rating >= s2.rating ? 0 : 1;
                    }
                    //one or 0 has a rating
                    if (s1.rating > 0) return 0;
                    //now maybe only 2 has a rating
                    if (s2.rating > 0) return 1;
                    //noone has a rating
                    return s1.area_desc.compareToIgnoreCase(s2.area_desc);
                }
            }
    );
```

If both objects s1 and s2 have no rating value set, I need to sort alphabetically.
I have read about this error in SO, but still cant figure out why this can crash.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically comparison have the following rules, and Comparator also need these rules.

1. compare(a,a) returns zero for all a
2. the sign of compare(a,b) must be the opposite of the sign of compare(b,a) for all pairs of (a,b)
3. From compare(a,b) > 0 and compare(b,c) > 0 it must follow compare(a,c) > 0 for all possible combinations of (a,b,c)

That error means that something violates one of these rules. You should return 0 if and only if they are equal. Change code like this.

```
Collections.sort(spinnerAreaArray, new Comparator<tarifdata>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(tarifdata s1, tarifdata s2) {
                if (s1.rating > 0 && s2.rating > 0) {
                    return s1.rating >= s2.rating ? -1 : 1;
                }
                //one or 0 has a rating
                if (s1.rating > 0) return -1;
                //now maybe only 2 has a rating
                if (s2.rating > 0) return 1;
                //noone has a rating
                return s1.area_desc.compareToIgnoreCase(s2.area_desc);
            }
        }
);
```